# Memory Leak in a Rust Program

Tags: windows, rust, performancecounter

I wrote a Rust program using windows-sys crate and collecting the performance counter values for query that is being supplied. I use the sample program provided by Microsoft team ([here](https://github.com/microsoft/windows-rs/tree/0.48.0/crates/samples/windows-sys)).

The program is able to retrieve the performance counter value. However when I checked process explorer to monitor the footprint, I noticed the below chart for private bytes. Since the private bytes is linearly increasing it points to memory leak.

[image]

I couldn't use windbg because windbg is not able to connect to microsoft symbol server. Hence I decided to manually identify the source of the problem by commenting out code and checking the private bytes. The relevant code is below -

```
fn execute_perf_query(input_query: &String,perf_query: &mut Vec<PerfEntryForMongo>)->f64{
    log::info!("Performing counter for  {:?}", input_query);

    let hostname = gethostname().into_string();
    
    unsafe {
        let mut query = 0;
        let p: *const u16 = std::ptr::null();
        
        PdhOpenQueryW(p, 0 as usize, &mut query);

    }

    return -1.0;
    //println!("Returning Now");
}
```

Please note, currently I have commented out code related to `PdhAddCounterW`, `PdhCollectQueryData`, and `PdhGetFormattedCounterValue` to understand impact of each windows call on private bytes.

`Vec<PerfEntryForMongo>` is being cleared after each iteration, and hence is not causing memory leak. `hostname` is a string and would be allocated on heap, however once the scope is ending, the memory would be freed.

I am using raw pointer, however it is a NULL pointer and shouldn't be allocating any memory in heap. What I need to understand, what is causing memory leak. I have covered the chapters related to reference, borrowing and unsafe Rust, yet I am not able to identify the cause of memory leak.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The [`PdhOpenQueryW()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/pdh/nf-pdh-pdhopenqueryw) call will create a resource and update the `query` handle.
You need to release the resource associated to this handle with [`PdhCloseQuery()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/pdh/nf-pdh-pdhclosequery).

Because all of this happens in an `unsafe` block, Rust trusts you and cannot decide on its own whether this resource should be released.

Each time this function is called, the created resource is leaked.

Comment: Technically a memleak is not unsafe either, so safety is not really a consideration here. `window-sys` is a -sys crate, and most of them don't add RAII wrappers, hence the query not getting closed automatically.

Comment: @Masklinn yes, you expressed it much better than I could have done, thanks a lot.